# Creating a dynamic item list and display the the item as per user subscription

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to create a dynamic item list of 2 column, but the list item will display as per the user subscription level and other not subscribed items will be hidden.

For example- 
I have 10 teams on the list

**Item List**
[image]

```html
<table width="640" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size:15px; color:#003057; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:18px; padding:0px 0 0px 0;">Your TV Choice lineup</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" height="15" style="line-height:15px;" ><img src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/Coding/Charter/TEMPLATES/CONTENT_ELEMENTS/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="15" style="display: block" border="0" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
         <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <!-- start if/then statement -->
            <tr>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#f5f5f7" height="25">
                  [COL A1]                
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <img src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/Coding/Charter/TEMPLATES/CONTENT_ELEMENTS/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="20" height="1" style="display: block" border="0" />
               </td>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#f5f5f7" height="25">
                  [COL B1]
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
            </tr>
            <!-- end if/then statement -->
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
         <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <!-- start if/then statement -->
            <tr>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="25">
                  [COL A2]                
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <img src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/Coding/Charter/TEMPLATES/CONTENT_ELEMENTS/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="20" height="1" style="display: block" border="0" />
               </td>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="25">
                  [COL B2]
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
            </tr>
            <!-- end if/then statement -->
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
         <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <!-- start if/then statement -->
            <tr>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#f5f5f7" height="25">
                  [COL A3]                
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <img src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/Coding/Charter/TEMPLATES/CONTENT_ELEMENTS/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="20" height="1" style="display: block" border="0" />
               </td>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#f5f5f7" height="25">
                  [COL B3]
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
            </tr>
            <!-- end if/then statement -->
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
         <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <!-- start if/then statement -->
            <tr>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="25">
                  [COL A4]                
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <img src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/Coding/Charter/TEMPLATES/CONTENT_ELEMENTS/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="20" height="1" style="display: block" border="0" />
               </td>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="25">
                  [COL B4]
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
            </tr>
            <!-- end if/then statement -->
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
         <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <!-- start if/then statement -->
            <tr>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#f5f5f7" height="25">
                  [COL A5]                
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <img src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/Coding/Charter/TEMPLATES/CONTENT_ELEMENTS/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="20" height="1" style="display: block" border="0" />
               </td>
               <!-- start if/then statement -->
               <td align="center" valign="middle" width="290" bgcolor="#f5f5f7" height="25">
                  [COL B5]
               </td>
               <!-- end if/then statement -->
            </tr>
            <!-- end if/then statement -->
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Scenario 1-**
If a user is only subscribed to 9 item from the index 0, and index 1 is not subscribed, so the list should be like below, and the not subscribes one will be hidden. (Item list will be shift one previous index)

**COL B5 was hidden**
[image: COL B5 was hidden]

**Scenario 2 -**
If a user is only subscribed to 5 item from the index 0, so the list should be like below, and the not subscribes one will be hidden.

**COL B3 to COL B5 was hidden**
[image: COL B3 to COL B5 was hidden]

I am somewhat familiar with HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery. I understand that there is a big resource of data for creating online, however, I don't think I found what I was looking for.

If anyone has any solution to this problem in JavaScript/jQuery, that's would be so helpful.

Comment: do you basically want a 2-column list no matter how many are subscribed, or could you clarify what constitutes whether something is A or B?

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thanks for the replay . Actually I want maximum item to be 10 and minimum would be 0, A ,B are just for 1st column and 2nd column prefix

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to use a table, there is an alternative way of doing this. (this will only partly answer the question as I'm not writing javascript at 2am Irish time)..

See the snippet below.. by creating a list with two columns, you can can create a list and then hide elements by setting the visibility to hidden using a "hidden" class. I made the "table" to have 6 rows a side, and then hid the first row to start off, otherwise the background-colour would have been off/uneven.  When you hide a list item, it will not affect the layout of the background-colour, just don't use display:none;

```css
#choices {
  text-align: center;
  width: 640px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  margin-top: -20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  column-count: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f5f5f7;
}
```

```html
<div id="choices">
  <h3>
    Your TV choices
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="hidden">col a1</li>
    <li>col a1</li>
    <li>col a2</li>
    <li>col a3</li>
    <li>col a4</li>
    <li>col a5</li>
    <li class="hidden">col a1</li>
    <li>col b1</li>
    <li>col b2</li>
    <li>col b3</li>
    <li>col b4</li>
    <li>col b5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This should get you started hopefully! Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8v4oyzc/) of the snippet with an element hidden

Comment: Hi Rachel, Just to clarify why I am looking the code in JavaScript is, the item that will display in the list will be selected randomly, and that might be 0 or less than equals to 10 . Only using css this hard to achieve . But thanks again,

Comment: You can use the CSS in conjunction with JavaScript. I can't do it now though, things to do. Hope you work it out. Might come back to you later if I can.